# time_t to string

Tags: c++, performance, datetime, formatting, boost

```
  std::string time_string;
  if ( time_t_var > 0 ) {
      time_string = boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string(boost::posix_time::from_time_t(time_t_var));
      boost::replace_all(time_string , "T" , " ");
  }
```

I have the above to get a `time_t` to a string in the format **Y:M:D H:M:S** or simply a blank string in the instances where `time_t` is `00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC`.

The code above is in a function called once a second so I'm looking to get this done as fast as possible, boost's way seems to need another function call to replace the 'T' and it's a `std::string` so I'm needing to convert it to `std::wstring` after.

Is there a quicker method of doing this preferably by using a `std::wstring` to begin with?

Comment: You could use `std::put_time`.

Comment: Or you could use [`std::time_put`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_put) and imbue the stream with it so that dates are always correctly formatted.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to do this with `std::put_time` as mentioned in a comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

std::wstring wtime(const time_t &t) {
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << std::put_time(&tm, L"%F %T");
    return wss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::wstring timestr = wtime(t);
    std::wcout << timestr;
}
```

Sample output:

> 2016-12-22 12:33:28

Note that unlike Boost, there is no fractional second, so if you need that, you are probably better off keeping Boost.  If that's the case, you can replace the unwanted `T` with this:

```
time_string[10] = ' ';
```

Since we know that the `T` character always is in the same place.

If this is really done once a second, it may be worthwhile to use a method that's often employed in embedded systems that need a text version of a clock: update a shared, read-only text version of the clock directly upon each tick.

Comment: Note to anybody who needs a `std::string` here instead of the `wstring`, you can modify the method given to use a `std::stringstream`, and remove the `L` from the second argument to `put_time`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the ctime functions would work for you.  This function will accept a time_t object and return the formatted wstring:

```
wstring GetTime(time_t& time_t_var)
{
    if ( time_t_var > 0 )
    {
        wchar_t buffer[30];
        wcsftime( buffer , 30 , L"%y:%m:%d %X" , localtime( &time_t_var ) );
        return buffer;
    }
    return L"";
}
```